# CSS - stack two elements on top of each other

Tags: css

I have a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-3l1oem?file=styled.ts,App.tsx)

This should be the simplest thing but I can't see why its not working.

I have react app with Typescript and a styled components, I'm sure none of that is the problem this is just css.

I'm trying to position two divs on top of each other.

The container has `position: relative;`

And then the div are absolutely positioned.

```
.FlexContainerColOne,
.FlexContainerColTwo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

But both div disappear, what am I missing

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: There is code included in this question, the link is because this is made with reactjs and the snippet in stackoverflow doesnt work with react. Please pay attention before you start commenting.

Answer (score 1):

From what I am seeing here is that they are not disappearing, you just can't see them because they don't have a width assigned or content. See the following, I added width, and opacity to show the two divs merging over each other.

[stackblitz snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-9uwbcd?file=styled.ts)

Result:

[image]

```css
flexcontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.FlexContainerColOne,
.FlexContainerColTwo {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.FlexContainerColOne {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.FlexContainerColTwo {
  background: green;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<flexcontainer>
  <div class="FlexContainerColOne"></div>
  <div class="FlexContainerColTwo"></div>
</flexcontainer>
```